# Adapter showing the last value in all tabs

Tags: android, dictionary

I am using maps in my app. Everything is fine except adapter. I don't know why it is showing only the last element in all tabs.

Here is my code:

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        List<Map<String,String>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String,String >>();

        Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();


        EmployeeDatabase empClick = new EmployeeDatabase(getApplicationContext());
        Cursor cursor = empClick.getDetails();
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                String age = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("age"));
                map.put("name",name);
                map.put("age",age);
                list.add(map);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
        }


        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.show_data, new String [] {"name", "age"}, new int[] {R.id.name,R.id.age});
        setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: Create your `HashMap` `Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();` inside `if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{.. `condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                map = new HashMap<String, String>();<-------Add this line
                String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));
                String age = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("age"));
                map.put("name",name);
                map.put("age",age);
                list.add(map);
            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            cursor.close();
        }
```

Comment: hey can u suggest me some good books for new experiments in android?

Comment: there is lot of books and sites on where u can learn android for this plz provide youe emailid so mailed you

Comment: its miss.grover89@gmail.com

Comment: it requires 15 reputation.. :(